# How To Check For Image On Page Rendered Late With JSON with Python

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping

I'm trying to go through a list of urls and check to see if a specific image is present.   I've tried selenium and beautiful soup and I can't figure it out.

The image looks like this.

```
    <div class="cmp-image-gallery" data-json="{&quot;src&quot;:&quot;.../thumbnails/product-thumbnail.png&quot;,&quot;templates&quot;:[&quot;.../en/brand-assets/thumbnails/product-thumbnail.png.{{width}}.resize/img.png&quot;],&quot;alt&quot;:&quot;Product&quot;,&quot;widths&quot;:[&quot;128&quot;,&quot;140&quot;,&quot;256&quot;,&quot;320&quot;,&quot;375&quot;,&quot;620&quot;]}"><div class="image-carousel"><div class="image-viewer-placeholder"><div style="display: block;"><div class="image-viewer-container"><div class="image-viewer-container__image-display"><figure class="image-viewer-container__image-figure image-viewer-container__image-figure--false image-viewer-container__image-figure--zoomin-false" style="background-image: url(&quot;.../en/brand-assets/thumbnails/product-thumbnail.png.660.resize/img.png&quot;); background-position: 50% 50%;"><img class="image-viewer-container__image-element" src=".../thumbnails/product-thumbnail.png.660.resize/img.png" alt="Product"></figure><div class="image-viewer-container__image-zoom"><div><div><div><div><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve" class="injected-svg" data-src=".../icons/zoom-in.svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><style>.st0{fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round}</style><circle class="st0" cx="10.6" cy="11" r="8.8"></circle><path class="st0" d="M21.6 22l-4.7-4.8M10.6 7.7v6.6M7.3 11h6.6"></path></svg></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="image-thumbnails-placeholder"></div></div></div>
```

Here's where I am at.

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')

image = json.loads(soup.find('div', class_='cmp-image-gallery').attrs['data-json'])


if image['src']:
    return True
else:
    return False


bool_results = []

for url in urls:
    print(url)
    # Make the response:
    resp = requests.get(url)
    # Parse the content with BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')
    
    try:
        image = json.loads(soup.find('div', class_='cmp-image-gallery').attrs['data-json'])
    except Exception as e:
        image = None
        print(e)
    
    if image is None:
        bool_results.append(False)
    elif instance(image, dict) and image.get('src'):
        bool_results.append(True)
    else:
        bool_results.append(False)
```

Comment: would help if you posted an image url or two you scraping.

Comment: https://www.waters.com/nextgen/us/en/shop/columns/wat046910-holder-kit-for-cartridge-and-guard-columns.html

Comment: this is the image url when there's no product image https://www.waters.com/content/dam/waters/en/brand-assets/thumbnails/product-thumbnail.png.660.resize/img.png  if it's this, then no image, otherwise, image. at least this is what i see when i spot check a couple items.

Comment: are you able to at least scrape the src url to check what it is? you didn't say what exactly you were having issues with

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')

with open('URLImgList.txt') as f:
    url_list = f.readlines()
url_list = [x.strip() for x in url_list]
with open('watersurls4.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for url in url_list:
        try:
            driver.get(url)
            img = driver.find_element_by_class_name("image-viewer-container__image-element").get_attribute("src")
            writer.writerow([url, img])
        except NoSuchElementException:
            writer.writerow([url, "No Image"])
driver.quit()
```